# Spring runner test return 404 for API test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I am writing API test cases for one of my controllers, but it is resulting with a 404.
I thought it would be a typo but it is not. Below are the code snippets.

RestController: `package: com.x.y.address.controller (src/main)`

```
@RestController
public class AddressInternalController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/v1/address-service/internal/company/address", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseStatus(OK)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<AddressModel> createCompanyAddress() 
            throws AddressException, BadRequestException {
        return ok("SUCCESS");
    }
}
```

My Test class: `package com.x.y.address.controller (src/test)`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestApp.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = AddressInternalController.class, secure = false)
public class AddressInternalControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void init() {}

    @Test
    public void createAddressTest_when_invalid_company() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(post("/v1/address-service/internal/company/address").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

My app uses spring security and to bypass that I have created a `TestAPP` class so that it will help me build only the config without security.

TestApp: package com.x.y.address (src/test)

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
// @ComponentScan({"com.x.y.address.controller.AddressInternalController"})
public class TestApp {
}
```

Above are the structure of the class.

Initially I thought may be the program does not scan the controller package and hence the 404. Hence added the componentScan. But that did not help.

Searched through a lot of stack over flow but most of the 404 are due to a type but it is not in my case.

Error log:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /v1/address-service/internal/company/address
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json]}
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

Any help shall be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `INTERNAL_ADDRESS_MAPPING` ?

Comment: Oh please ignore that. I will edit the post. I added that value directly unto the PostMapping

Comment: shouldnt `@ResponseStatus(OK)` be `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
// @ComponentScan({"com.x.y.address.controller.AddressInternalController"})
public class TestApp {
}
```

with:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
// @ComponentScan({"com.x.y.address.controller.AddressInternalController"})
public class TestApp {
}
```

and it worked.

---

UPDATE 1:

I noticed, in your `@ComponentScan` you use the path to the class itself, but you should point to the package with your controller. If you want to specify a class, use `basePackageClasses` property of `@ComponentScan`

Comment: Tried with this also. It did not help. TestApp is under src/test not under src/main. Is this the reason mine did not work ?

Comment: In my case it is also under src/test

Comment: It worked! Last time I forgot to uncomment componentScan.

Comment: Can you please explain your fix?

Comment: @bibliophilsagar for an explanation, please look at UPDATE 1, I think the problem is you forgot to use `basePackageClasses` instead of `basePackages`.